# Нужно получить несколько ответов от сервера сделав один запрос

Tags: reactjs, express

Суть таски такова:
Есть страница, на которой можно выгрузить на сайт все посты, и в момент ожидания окончания должны приходить ответы от сервера на каком этапе сейчас идет выгрузка. В консоли удается получить эти строки одну за другой, но не могу получить их на фронте потому что вылетает ошибка 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT, если ответов больше чем 1

Comment: Может вам стоит рассмотреть сокеты или лонгпул?

Comment: Сервер не будет отвечать несколько раз на один запрос HTTP. Если тебе нужно несколько ответов - делай несколько запросов.